# Java EE 7 Compatible servers?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x, java-ee-7, jakarta-ee

I am using JAVA SE 1.7 and JAVA EE 7 in project,
what are all the available servers(commercial/free) which will support JAVA EE 7 web profile 2.1?(Required Components). I need to use Servlet 3.1 and CDI 1.1 ..etc.
[javaee-spec_WebProfile](https://java.net/downloads/javaee-spec/WebProfile.pdf)

I try to use JBoss EAP 6.1 / Jboss 7, but I came to know it'll support [JAVA EE 6 web profile](http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDEV/road-map-for-java-ee6-web-profile.html). ([web-profile1](https://access.redhat.com/site/articles/112673), [web-profile2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7649023/1213738))

I found [JAVA EE 7 compatible](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html) servers are GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0, TMAX JEUS 8.

Any other servers available?

Answer (score 6):

Here is an list of [Certified_application_servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE#Certified_application_servers), both of **GlassFish server Open Source Edition v4.0** ,**WildFly v8.0.0.Final**, **TmaxSoft JEUS v8** are Java EE 7 full certified.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is also [WildFly 8](http://www.wildfly.org), renamed JBossAS.
which is nearing CR1 this weak.
Most of EE7 stuff works, TCK for EE7 is almost passing and when it is, it will enter certification process which will then result into showing up on the web page you linked.

I would say that you should give WildFly a try if noting else.

Comment: Hi Tomaz Cerar, You are correct in the sense of JAVA EE 7 stuff,
whether WildFly EE7 full web profile certifed?
I don't have much knowledge in LGPL, if I need to use wildfly to develop client applications(in office), should I/company need to buy?
and what are the licensing and security Issues need to take care?
could yo please help me on this!

Answer (score 4):

You can use WildFly 8 but It does not have commercial support by RedHat yet. So, you can use it for anything but you have to wait for the next EAP version if you want to have official support. LGPL is not a problem, you can use it to build any applications however I suggest to use an Application server with commercial support once you need to deploy to production but this should depends of your applications needs.